# Resolve NULL fields using CTEs or CASE statements in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got users with an ID (`u_ID`) and a name (`u_Name`) which are in organizational units which have an `org_ID` and are structured hierarchically (the superordinated unit's ID is the `upper_ID`). Every user also belongs to a coordinator with an ID (`c_ID`) and a name (`c_Name`). A coordinator belongs to a unit. If there is no coordinator for an organizational unit, the user belongs to the coordinator of it's superordinated unit.

If I simply request the coordinators for all users, my result looks like this:

```
c_ID     c_Name    u_ID     u_Name    org_ID    upper_ID
----     ------    ----     ------    ------    --------
648      foo       568      name1     111       555
NULL     NULL      743      name2     333       111
NULL     NULL      237      name3     666       333
058      bar       671      name4     222       777
571      fox       197      name5     444       777
```

To resolve the `NULL` fields I need to user the `upper_ID`'s coordinator. Can anybody tell me how I can solve this using T-SQL?

I've got something like recursive CTEs or CASE expression in my mind, but I can't get anything to work.

My expected result looks like this:

```
c_ID     c_Name    u_ID     u_Name    org_ID    upper_ID
----     ------    ----     ------    ------    --------
648      foo       568      name1     111       555
648      foo       743      name2     333       111
648      foo       237      name3     666       333
058      bar       671      name4     222       777
571      fox       197      name5     444       777
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, and show us your current query attempt.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields. And case _expression_, not statement...

Comment: @jarlh well it's not a `NULL` column, just one entry. How do you "SQL-guys" call this?

Comment: Is it *users* or *org units* that have coordinators? Because you start off saying one and then seem to switch to saying the other. It would be much clearer if you posted `CREATE TABLE` statements alongside your *narrative*, and *sample data* that matches your expected results.

Comment: It would help to see your current query...

Comment: Does this have any limit on the level of parent can be

Comment: @Shnugo I actually don't have anything to show you, since I had to simplify my data quite a lot to deliver an example.

Comment: @SanalSunny yes, there are maximum four levels

Comment: Then *deliver* an example. You've in your head chopped out irrelevant details to give us this example - so make that real and concrete so that we can execute your cut down query again sample data and so we can *test* solutions easily as well. Otherwise, you leave us having to create our own sample data based on incomplete information and so no way of knowing if it's anywhere close to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Recursive CTE` to retrieve the results

```
;with cte
AS(
   SELECT c_ID, c_Name,u_ID,u_Name,org_ID,upper_ID
   FROM tbl AS  t
   WHERE c_ID IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.c_ID,c.c_Name,t.u_ID,t.u_Name,t.org_ID,t.upper_ID
   FROM tbl t
   JOIN cte c ON t.upper_ID=c.org_ID 
   WHERE t.c_ID IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

**[DEMO!](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=afee4e2204d8ae0e6ed28c9c64e1d7f2)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use recursive CTE.

Possible implementation plan:

1. Define the recursive member first. You need to think backwards. When the recursion should stop? Certainly, when a **c_ID** is found.
   Therefore you need to add a derived field to your CTE called
   **upper_c_ID** and pick there **c_ID** of the superordinated unit. This way
   when you join **org_ID** to **upper_ID** you need to add **AND upper_c_ID IS
   NOT NULL** - in this case a previous join has already found one and
   lookup can stop. You also need to add a field called **original_u_ID**
   which should come from the anchor member's **u_ID** and should not
   change because otherwise in the end you wouldn't be able see which one started the recursion.
2. Define the anchor member. You need to add **upper_c_ID** here as well as **original_u_ID**, both fields picked from **c_ID** and
   **u_ID**,
   respectively. You can also put a filter here e.g. if you want only
   the lowest level org_ID's that are not superordinated units.
3. After the CTE definition filter on **upper_c_ID IS NOT NULL**, and that should be your missing c_ID for the u_ID in question, which is
   in this case the **original_u_ID**. Depending on what filter you put in
   the anchor member you need to add filters here.